# Указатель на необъявленный тип

Tags: c++

Надо, чтобы структура `Student` хранила в себе указатель типа `Group`.

Возможно ли это реализовать?

```
struct Student
{
    string name, surname, patronym;
    uint age;
    Group* group;
};
struct Group
{
    uint numberOfGroup, numberOfGroupStudents;
    vector <Student> students;
    Year* year;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Либо так:

```
struct Student
{
    string name, surname, patronym;
    uint age;
    struct Group* group;
//  ^~~~~~
};
struct Group
{
    uint numberOfGroup, numberOfGroupStudents;
    vector <Student> students;
    Year* year;
};
```

Либо вот так:

```
struct Group; // <--

struct Student
{
    string name, surname, patronym;
    uint age;
    Group* group;
};
struct Group
{
    uint numberOfGroup, numberOfGroupStudents;
    vector <Student> students;
    Year* year;
};
```